# Exact docutils equivalent for :ref:

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

The following ReStructuredText contains the `:ref:` role, which is a Sphinx-extension:

```
Read more in :ref:`section-target`.

.. _section-target:

Section Title
=============
Text body.
```

Where

```
:ref:`section-target`
```

is parsed to the following doctree:

```
<reference internal="True" refid="section-target"><inline classes="std std-ref">Section Title</inline></reference>
```

You can reproduce this by storing the above reStructuredText into `sphinx_input/index.rst` and run `sphinx-build -b xml -C sphinx_input sphinx_ouptut`.

Is there an equivalent that I can use to generate this exact same doctree that only uses [docutils restructuredtext](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html)? (Thus no Sphinx-specific roles or directives). I don't care about readability, since this will be machine-parsed only.

So far, the closest I got was:

```
`Section Title <section-target>`_
```

which resulted in:

```
<reference name="Section Title" refuri="section-target">Section Title</reference>
```

That's close, but it defines a `refuri`, not a `refid`.

Regretfully, the [documentation of the `reference` doctree](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#reference) is missing.

Comment: How did you convert the doctree contents to human readable form?

Comment: @bad_coder: in this case the output is xml, but my question is what is the best input, not about the output.

Comment: Ok, but when I generate my doctress as usual I get the pickled file that is full of unreadable characters. I want to generate a readeable XML file like you are showing, that's why I'm asking. It would make it easier for me to answer the question.

Comment: @bad_coder. I added the command to reproduce in the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approximation is a hyperlink element,

```
Read more in `Section Title`_.
```

which produces `<reference name="Section Title" refid="section-title">Section Title</reference>`.

If the link text should differ from the reference name, you may use an embedded reference with trailing underscore (cf. [Embedded URIs and Aliases](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#embedded-uris-and-aliases)).
Use two underscores after the closing backtick to make the reference *anonymous*:

```
Read more in `Section Title <section-target_>`__.
```

Things get more complicated if also you need the link text in an `<inline  classes="std std-ref">` node.
You need a substitution for every link (as rST does not support nested inline markup) and one custom role:

```
.. role:: ersatz-ref
   :class: std std-ref

.. |section-target| replace:: :ersatz-ref:`Section Title`

Read more in |section-target|_
```

This results in `<reference refid="section-target"><inline classes="std std-ref">Section Title</inline></reference>`.

The remaining difference is the missing `internal="True"` flag, that cannot be reproduced. However, the Docutils HTML writer will still add `class="reference internal"` to the generated anchor element.

**Caveat:**
While it is possible to get close to the orginal doctree element with standard rST constructs, the replacement rsT constructs will not work for reference targets in other documents of the Sphinx project.

OTOH, a hyperref target defined with the standard syntax, e.g., `_section-target:`
can be referenced in other documents of the Sphinx project if compiled with Sphinx (but not if the other document is compiled stand-alone with Docutils).

Comment: Not exactly a `:ref:` because that anonymous target won't work across documents. Or would it?

Comment: The "reference name" is always local to a document in plain Docutils. Hyperlinks to other documents must use the HTML anchor, e.g. `Section Title <other-page.html#section-title>`__`. See the Docutils documentation sources, e.g., https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/config.txt,  for plenty of examples. Yes, this is inconvenient – this is why Sphinx was invented.